# Three-times differentiable function

Tags: solution-verification, vector-analysis, vector-fields

Let $\mathbf a:\mathbb{R}\longrightarrow\mathbb{R^3}$ be a three-times differentiable vector valued function. If $\mathbf b(x)=\mathbf a(x)\cdot[\mathbf a'(x) \times\mathbf a''(x)]$   (eq $1$),

Show that:

$$\mathbf b'(x)=\mathbf a(x)\cdot\bigl[\mathbf a'(x) \times\mathbf a'''(x)\bigr]$$

**What I have tried:**

I think that to differentiate the RHS of the eq $1$ I use the product rule. So :

$\mathbf b'(x)=\mathbf a''(x)\cdot[\mathbf a(x)\times \mathbf a'(x)] -\mathbf a'(x)\cdot[\mathbf a(x)\times \mathbf a''(x)]$

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: @SebastianCor I have added what I have tried to the bottom of my post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**:
Apply the rules for the dot product and the cross product:
\begin{align}
\mathbf b(x)'&=\mathbf a'(x)\cdot\bigl[\mathbf a'(x) \times\mathbf a''(x)\bigr]+\mathbf a(x)\cdot\bigl[\bigl(\mathbf a'(x) \times\mathbf a''(x)\bigr)'\bigr]\\
&=\mathbf a'(x)\cdot\bigl[\mathbf a'(x) \times\mathbf a''(x)\bigr]+\mathbf a(x)\cdot\bigl[\mathbf a''(x) \times\mathbf a''(x)+\mathbf a'(x) \times\mathbf a'''(x)  \bigr].
\end{align}

Comment: Okay and so in the second square bracket in the last line the first set of cross product is 0?

Comment: Absolutely (and the first term is $0$ too, since it's a determinant).

Comment: I don't understand why the determinant gives 0

Comment: Simply because two column-vectors are the same.

Comment: could you elaborate, I'm still a bit confused on how it gives 0?

Comment: The determinant is an *alternating* multilinear form, so, by definition it is $0$ if any two vectors are equal, and more generally, if the vectors are linearly dependent.